# Do not use .htpasswd when env set to specific value

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, php-cli

I have `.htpasswd` protection on my site that works fine. When I call a script that puts everything into cache via PHP CLI I get a 401 error. The problem here is the `.htpasswd protection`.

In the CLI call I define my env (`ENV=cron`), how can I tell my `.htaccess` to not ask for the username and password if `env=cron`?

My current code in the `.htaccess` is:

```
<IfDefine env!=cron>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "internal"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/my/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</IfDefine>
```

I am using apache 2.2 and not 2.4 which would make this a whole lot easier. 
What is the correct way of solving this issue?

Comment: I hope you're using Apache httpd 2.4 and the 2.2 tag is an error.

Comment: @HBruijn `apachectl -v 
Server version: Apache/2.2.34 (Unix)`

Comment: I think you need to upgrade to 2.4 to be able to configure [`RequireAny`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireany) where different authentication methods for the same resource can be combined and allow access if either condition is met.   - If your cronjob runs on the webserver, don't make a HTTP request but simply execute your php code with the PHP command line interpreter `/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/your.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Apache 2.2 you may be able to do this with the help of the `Satisfy` directive.

For example:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "internal"
AuthUserFile /path/to/my/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=cron
Satisfy Any
```

(The default is `Satisfy All`)

The `<IfDefine>` directive (on Apache 2.2) is only able to check whether parameters have been set on the command line when Apache is started. It cannot check environment variables.